# How to transfer one element from a list to another list

Tags: java, user-interface

I basically made this thing where the user highlights a list of food and presses the '>>' button which transfers the food from the left hand side to the right hand side and vice versa with the '<<' button.
Only trouble I'm having is actually doing that. Im gone far enough to make it appear on the designated list BUT it only transfers one of the food to the list. E.g. If you selected 'Tuna' and 'Mayo', then only 'Tuna' would get transfered to the appropreiate list. 
Heres the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MAIN extends JFrame {

    Button ltor, rtol;
    JList homelist, shoppinglist;
    DefaultListModel homefoodlist = new DefaultListModel();
    DefaultListModel shoppingfoodlist = new DefaultListModel();
    JTextField foodlog;

    String[] hfood = { "Tuna", "Mayo", "Ketchup", "Sun Flower Oil", "Buscuits",
            "Cookies", "Turkey" };
    String[] sfood = { "Chocolate", "bread", "Milk", "Toast", "Beef", "Chicken" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MAIN();

    }

    private MAIN() {
        JPanel thepanel = new JPanel();
        thehandler handler = new thehandler();

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("Shopping List");
        this.add(thepanel);

        // Creating the Home List(left list)
        for (String homefood : hfood) {
            homefoodlist.addElement(homefood);
        }

        homelist = new JList(homefoodlist);
        homelist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        thepanel.add(homelist);

        // Buttons for moving lists from left to right
        ltor = new Button(">>");
        thepanel.add(ltor);
        ltor.addActionListener(handler);

        rtol = new Button("<<");
        rtol.addActionListener(handler);
        thepanel.add(rtol);

        // Creating the Shopping list(right list)
        for (String shoppingfood : sfood) {
            shoppingfoodlist.addElement(shoppingfood);
        }
        shoppinglist = new JList(shoppingfoodlist);
        shoppinglist
                .setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        thepanel.add(shoppinglist);

    }

    // ActionListener

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // The HomeList to the ShoppingList
            if (e.getSource() == ltor) {
                if (homelist.isSelectionEmpty() == false) {
                    for(String x : hfood) {
                        if (x == homelist.getSelectedValue()) {
                            shoppingfoodlist.addElement(x);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
}
}
}
```

EDIT == Just fixed it but for some reason I cant do the reverse (e.g. from shoppinglist to homelist. This is my code for the action listeners

```
if (e.getSource() == ltor) {
                if (homelist.isSelectionEmpty() == false) {
                    for (String x : hfood) {
                        for (String y : homelist.getSelectedValuesList()) {
                            if (x.equals(y)) {
                                shoppingfoodlist.addElement(x);
                                homefoodlist.removeElement(x);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (e.getSource() == rtol) {
                        if (shoppinglist.isSelectionEmpty() == false) {

                            for (String x : sfood) {
                                for (String y : shoppinglist
                                        .getSelectedValuesList()) {
                                    if (x.equals(y)) {
                                        homefoodlist.addElement(x);
                                        shoppingfoodlist.removeElement(x);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but:

```
for(String x : hfood) {
  if (x == homelist.getSelectedValue()) {
    shoppingfoodlist.addElement(x);
  }
}
```

If you select two items from the first list and move them, this is only going to work for the first selected item. You need to make sure you're keeping track of all the selected items, and  grabbing them appropriately.

Another thing, it looks like you're comparing `String`s with `==`..don't do this in Java. Use `.equals()`

```
for(String x : hfood) {
  for (String y : homelist.getSelectedValuesList()) {
    if (x.equals(y)))
      shoppingfoodlist.addElement(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but im getting an error. On the part where is says:
for(String y : homelist.getSelectedValuesList())
its giving me an error that says: cannot convert from element to string.

Comment: You need to make sure your `JList` is bounded to `String`s..`JList<String> homelist`

Comment: @user2638788, have you tried the other suggestions? The nested for loop code makes no sense. There is no need to iterate through all the values in the array, just to see if the item is also a selected value.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. I have one problem now. I cant do the reverse (e.g. from shoppinglist to homelist). Edited the question with new code now

Comment: `I have one problem now. I cant do the reverse` Did you try the other suggestions? I already told you why this solution was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `getSelectedListValues()` method to return a List of all the selected objects.

Then I would iterated through this List and a) remove each Item from the DefaultListModel of the first JList and b) add the Item to the model of the second JList.

```
DefaultListModel model1 = (DefaultListModel)list1.getModel();
DefaultListModel model2 = (DefaultListModel)list2.getModel();

for (Object item: list1.getSelectedListValues())
{
    model1.removeElement(item);
    model2.addElement(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want getSelectedValues(), which returns an array, instead of getSelectedValue(), which only returns the first selected value.

Comment: getSelectedValues() has been depreciated from 1.7

Comment: true, but since the OP was using getSelectedValue(), I'm guessing that they're using 1.6

Answer (score 0):

So this is where you are getting it wrong

```
for(String x : hfood) {
      if (x == homelist.getSelectedValue()) {
        shoppingfoodlist.addElement(x);
      }
    }
```

You should try something like this

ArrayList(or whatever data structure is applicable for this) selectedValues = hfood.getSelectedValues();

```
for(String x : selectedValues) {

        shoppingfoodlist.addElement(x);

    }
```